# Preventing stale data in react-native

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-native, fetch, invalidation

This will be more open-minded question, maybe not limited only to react-native.

I have a typical search list that is taken from our backend. I am trying to find the best way to prevent stale data being shown for user - especially if they minimize the application and go back to it later. I was thinking about using https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer this, but maybe there's a better way to achieve this?

Also as a quick note my stack is : react-navigation, redux, redux-persist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good question, but my answer will not in  the **code** scope.

Data being stale whenever it was seen by user.

At the view point of a product maker. The best way to make your data slow to being stale is **"Dont show all you have"**.

So, How can we implement that theory ?

Almost of peoples do not really pay attention to what they see. They will forget anythings as soon as possible, what don't pin their eyes on.

Thus, you don't need a timer system to check and shuffle your data. Track the user behavior is a more complex but effecient solution.

It can be done both in your client or your server.

*Simple example:*

Store the time point when user saw your data (maybe in AsyncStorage), make a logic to check and chooose to renew or not  in the next time your user come back.

It is very simpler and lightweight solution than using timer system.

*More Complex example:*

Track the user session, type of content they view, and how much time they spend on this content.

Replace the viewed content by the relation contents of they viewed things.

```
Note: The rn-background-timer work not as good as they advertised.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you don't really need to use a separate library to achieve the desired behavior.

You already have an event for [AppState](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html) natively from react-native and events for listening screen states from react-navigation library ([`addListener`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html)). You can combine these events and detect changes for the app and re-render your search results or reset data.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I knew about AppState, but I want to prevent stale data even if the user didn't minimize the app. I guess this is all about some time threshold